# C and assembly how can it work?

Tags: c, assembly

I am wondering how mixing C and assembly can be possible as compilers generate code in different ways, for example many C compilers will use registers rather than pushing to the stack while making a function call, These functions will then move those registers into the appropiate memory locations because of this what if you write assembly code or link with an object file created by a different compiler that will call the C function but instead push the arguments to the stack rather than set the registers.

My guess is the C compiler assembly output has done it in such a clever way that it doesn't make a difference and it will still work but I can't be sure looking at the assembly code it doesn't appear it would work.

Can anyone answer my question as I am writing a compiler and need to know this so I don't make any mistakes should I want to link with a C module in the future.

Comment: The C code and the assembly code must follow the same calling convention. If they use a different convention then likely you'll get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: _" many C compilers will use registers rather than pushing to the stack while making a function call"_ Not really. There are "calling conventions" that compilers will follow.

Comment: Just to have it mentioned: *inline assembly* doesn't necessarily need to comply with **any** calling convention, just with register usage (not that I would in any way favor that)

Comment: you have the same problem with two c functions being mixed together.  Thus the need for a set of rules, calling convention, what registers each function (in whatever language it is) must preserve, what registers they can trash, put the stack back the way you found, it, and so on.  Allows for multiple functions of any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventions that are used for calling functions are part of what's called the "application binary interface" (ABI). If this interface is *specified*, then all code that follows the specification can be linked together.

There is no standard ABI for C. However, most popular platforms have one prevailing C compiler that effectively produces a de-facto standard ABI (e.g. there's one for Windows, one for Linux on x86 (32 and 64 bit), one for Linux on ARM, etc.). ABIs may specify a large number of separate "calling conventions", and your C compiler will typically let you specify the desired convention at the point of function declaration using some vendor extension.

Conversely, if there is no documented ABI for your C compiler, or for an existing bit of object code, then you cannot in general link (or otherwise interact) with it successfully.

Comment: I see so essentially this interface is more of a specification and I should write my compiler to generate code compatible with the specification I choose.

Comment: @Daniel - If you write your own compiler, this is all *your* choice and you can use any calling convention you like. Adapting to the local C convention could be a separate thing. For example, in C++ we write `extern "C" void func();` to make `func` compatible with the C language.